# Running Faust Agent Synchronously

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, faust

Check the below code

```
@app.agent()
async def process(stream):
    async for value in stream.take(5000, within=5):
        process(value)
```

The agent takes 5000 records within 5 seconds asynchronously and process them. I don't want the agent to pick another 5000 thousand records until the processing of previous one is finished. Basically I want to run the agent **Synchronously**. Is there a way we can do it?

Comment: just to know, is last record getting processed in faust, when using the take method ? https://github.com/robinhood/faust/issues/656

Comment: @Learnis I am using `take` method in production, I haven't faced any such issue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the following code to see whether the worker is executing second batch of record while the processing of first batch has not yet finished

```
@app.agent()
async def process(stream):
    async for value in stream.take(5000, within=5):
        print(1)
        await async.sleep(30)
```

The worker printed `1` and waited for 30 seconds to print `2`. The await statement gives control back to the event loop but in this case it waited which implies that the batches are executed one after the another. Hence this is synchronous.

PS. Committing offset, rebalancing, monitoring etc are asynchronous operations which are handled by event loop.

Comment: As you are using the take method here After you take 5000 records from kafka, suppose because of some issue the worker goes down immediately after you processed the 2k records out of 5k records. In this case, once after the restart you will process those 2k records twice right ? how do you handle those kind of scenarios

Answer (score 1):

I think you could set the [concurrency](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/agents.html#concurrency) to 1 on the agent and that'd effectively render it synchronous.

You might also find modifying the [topic partitions](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/settings.html?highlight=topic#topic-partitions) to be useful if you do that but I don't have a complete understanding of the relationship between these two settings (just wanted to point out a potentially useful avenue).